# What is the default MySQL wait_timeout and interactive_timeout value?

Tags: mysql, timeout

I changed these timeouts globally with:

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=30; SET GLOBAL interactive_timeout=30
```

and noticed that I have another application running which got problems with these "low" timeouts. So I would like to undo this and only apply it to the specific database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to the *MySQL Manual* the default values for [`wait_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and for [`interactive_timeout`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) are  - `28800`.

> On thread startup, the session wait_timeout value is initialized from the global
>   **wait_timeout** value or from the global **interactive_timeout** value, depending on the 
>   type of client (as defined by the CLIENT_INTERACTIVE connect option to 
>   mysql_real_connect()). See also interactive_timeout.

Comment: thanks, so these are in milliseconds and with "SET GLOBAL wait_timeout=30;" its in seconds ?

Comment: As on the manual it's said that this time is in seconds! (which is weird for me). 28800 - 8 hours?. It should be in milliseconds and the reason you're having the problem is that 30 milliseconds is to little.  It's also said that its scope is session wide. Thus, restarting `mysqld`  should solve the problem.

Comment: if the default value of 28800 is in seconds this would be 8 hours. If it is in milliseconds it would be 28,8 seconds so I would have increased it. That sounds odd, like you said. But since I change these two values a program is shouting "FATA: DataSourcePool is donw!!!!" -> The last packet successfully received from the server was 30,003 milliseconds ago." which fits my changed settings

Comment: I have updated the comment above, please take a look!

Comment: are you sure about this, take a look here:
http://serverfault.com/questions/355750/mysql-lowering-wait-timeout-value-to-lower-number-of-open-connections

Comment: another thing which I don´t understand is, I have another application which when it restarts doesn´t close the db pools, so I thought I decrease the timeout. But the restart takes 2-3 minutes so it should timeout by default, which it doesn´t.

Comment: As sure I am as I believe the manual! I think, there is no real reason to change that default value. Besides, it appears that (see comment): `There's a difference between queries and connections. You need to at least ensure your web site software won't break if a shorter wait_timeout cause a connection to close when the software expects it to remain open. `

Comment: yeah you are right. but my hands are tide with third party closed source software

Comment: Think again, the default value is 28800 and you want it to be 30?? It's a huge change by `960` times :)) Anything could be different, if you change it almost in 1000 times..

Comment: Nah the thing I don´t understand is this: The application needs about 2-3 min. to restart and shouts about not closed connection pools after startup. I don´t know why they don´t get closed, but by this the 30 seconds are over and so the connection should have been timedout

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to do. But by default, as far as I know, if you query something from database, the connections stays open..

Comment: Well I got it back on default. Thanks for you help :) I might have to talk to the devs of the software, why the hell they don´t close the connections on restart.

Comment: You're welcome. If you find out something, post back to me please!

Answer (score 13):

I have the same problem in `5.5.43`. I was having the "**has gone away**" error message for some long queries beyond about 2 minutes. So I tried these 3:

(1) `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_%';`

(2) `SHOW global VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_%';` and

(3) `SHOW session VARIABLES LIKE 'wait_%';` .

All showed wait_timeout to be `28800`. Then I added `wait_timeout = 31536000` to `/etc/my.cnf`. Then my long query was able to complete. And from the 3 ways of showing variables above, only  (2) the one with "global" showed a change from 28800 to 31536000. The other 2 were unaffected.  Since my long-query was definitely less than 10 minutes long, does this mean that the unit of time used here was **milliseconds** rather than **seconds**?

Comment: Is there an official answer on this? If this is indeed miliseconds and not seconds, it's a very serious documentation error...

Comment: It is in seconds. It doesn't show up on the above (1) and (3) queries because you need to start a new session as you are looking at the session variables that were set when you started the session (which was before you changed the `wait_timeout` value)

Answer (score 11):

Referring to the MySQL Manual the default values for -

[wait_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and for [interactive_timeout](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout) are - 28800 **seconds**

> REMEMBER - **seconds** (28800 in **seconds**)