ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away (Declare variables within MySQL interactive session)
Following on How to declare a variable in MySQL?
Say I initialize variables using SET or SELECT statement within MySQL interactive session:
SET @start = 1, @finish = 10;    
or
SELECT @start := 1, @finish := 10;
I can see/verify that they're defined fine, using
SELECT @start, @finish;
However, it won't last long -- when I run the above SELECT again and they both become NULL:
SELECT @start, @finish;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
+--------+---------+
| @start | @finish |
+--------+---------+
| NULL   | NULL    |
+--------+---------+

When they're gone, I see
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...


Which timeout value control such "forgetting" behavior?
Can I make it longer please?


'User-defined variables are session specific' https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/user-variables.html ie there is no timeout value on user defined variables..

Also ref. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076306/what-is-the-default-mysql-wait-timeout-and-interactive-timeout-value
